# XCODE exec file only runs after stopping the program

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, sfml

I have recently been building a C++ program "SFML_start" on XCode utilizing the SFML library which was going good. Ever since I upgraded to macOS Big Sur yesterday, whenever I run the C++ program the exec file doesn't run at all but the message dialog says "Running SFML_start" after the build is complete. I have noticed that the exec file runs after I stop the program, but I need to do some real time debugging too, which gets cancelled the moment I stop the program. Does anybody know how to overcome this problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you run the program from the terminal? Can you run it under `lldb`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED: This problem still persisted even when I updated Xcode to the latest version compatible with macOS Big Sur. However, after completely creating a new duplicate project "SFML_refined" under the updated SDK and rebuilding it, the exec file was successfully run. It is worth noting that the "SFML_start" however still doesn't run the exec file.